# How to fill by color created rectanglein on the image?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to fill by color created rectanglein on the image in pictuteBox control.

Here is my segment code:

```
       foreach (var item in foundShapes.fMergedSignesCollection)
        {
            Graphics gr = pbContainer.CreateGraphics();

            Rectangle signsWrapper = item[0].contour.SourceBoundingRect;  //rude solution
            for (int j = 1; j < item.Count; j++)
            {
                signsWrapper = Rectangle.Union(signsWrapper, item[j].contour.SourceBoundingRect);

            }

            gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Chocolate, signsWrapper);
        }
        pbContainer.Image = img.ToBitmap();
```

But I don't get wanted result, I don't the the filled by color rectangle.

Any idea why I can't see the colored rectangle and how to fix the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you putting this code in the Paint() event of your form?

Comment: No,it is in method : private void WrapFoundShapes(FoundContours foundShapes)

the method is member of the Form